# Archiving data in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, archive

**EDIT**

Let me adjust my question, if I wrote a script that copies a current mysql table to an archiving table then delete the records from the original table how can I make sure the auto increment is preserved? I need to make sure the primary keys are not duplicated in the archived tables.

Comment: What makes this question different from [your previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215216/mysql-archiving-data-which-solution-to-use)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to archive live MySQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65093/best-way-to-archive-live-mysql-database)

Comment: @Matt Ball Yes, Im not good at telling jokes.

Comment: What makes you think that primary key of source table has to match primary key of archiving table?

Comment: @Michael J.V. All I was saying is I wanted to keep the auto incremented value in tack. So if the primary auto incremented key in the live table was 35, then I moved them to the archived table and deleted the rows in the live table, the next value in the live table should be 36. I need to keep them the same because in the archive tables the key is referenced in other tables and I need that reference to be maintained for reporting purposes.

Comment: @Matt Ball BTW when I meant geez I meant geez cant believe I forgot I posted about this earlier. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to preserve the primary key position in the archiving table. Just make sure that when you copy to the archiving table you use INSERT **IGNORE** INTO... and you won't need to worry about duplicate entries into the archiving table. Then simply use a unique constraint on the column of the primary key in the archiving table. You should not have an auto-incrementing primary key on your archiving table.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How would I make sure though that the live table has the correct keys? Maybe Im over thinking this? When I delete the rows from the live table the next rows adding to the live table should start at the next auto increment value. Just concerned if something happened the primary key value will get mixed up. Because when I run reports off the archive table it needs to join to other tables so the primary key needs to be preserved.

Comment: @John - A MySQL MYISAM table will reset the increment value if you truncate the table, but it will retain that value if you simply delete the rows. So, if it has 1000 entries, and you DELETE those 1000, the next auto increment should still be 1001, not 1. You can also manually set that value using "ALTER TABLE  `tableName` AUTO_INCREMENT =101" where 101 is your value.